# Access the existing List command bar in SPFX command-set project

Tags: spfx, modern-experience, modern-document-library, command-set

I am trying to access the List view command bar in commnd-set spfx project but no success. I am trying below code:

```
const compareOneCommand: Command = this.tryGetCommand('COMMAND_1');
    if (compareOneCommand) {
      // This command should be hidden unless exactly one row is selected.
      compareOneCommand.visible = event.selectedRows.length === 1;
    }
    //custom
    const upld :Command = this.tryGetCommand('Upload');
    if(upld){
      alert('upload found');
      upld.visible = false;
    }
    //end
```

I am able to get custom command 'Command_1' but no Luck with 'Upload' Button. 
The intention is to hide the **Upload** Button in modern Library experience.

Please help me out.. Urgently needed!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this possible?